# Confused about permutation cycles - Question on joint cycles of odd length

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

For some reason I'm finding permutation cycles to be strange and hard to deal with.

> Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be cycles of odd length (not disjoint).  Prove that if $\alpha^2 = \beta^2$, then $\alpha = \beta$.

I don't see what the odd lengths of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have to do with anything.  I see that they are even permutations.  I see that $\alpha^2 = \beta^2 \implies \alpha^2\beta^{-2} = \varepsilon$.  I don't think that helps.  I don't know.  The book went over the proof that a permutation can't be both odd and even, but I don't see anything in the proof that helps.

If $\alpha = (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_s)$, then $\alpha^2 = (a_1, a_3, \dots, a_s, a_2, \dots, a_{s-1})$.  If $\beta = (b_1, b_2, \dots, b_r)$, then $\beta^2 = (b_1, b_3, \dots, b_r, b_2, \dots, b_{r-1})$.  I don't see how to match up the elements of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ if I'm using different letters, but I can't use the same letters because I don't know which ones are the same or different.  And maybe they are the same, but what if one of the cycles is rotated and starts on a different element?  How do you deal with things like this?

---

**Edit:** Is the following proof sound?

The only way for $\alpha^2$ to be equal to $\beta^2$ while $\alpha \neq \beta$ is for $\alpha^2$ and $\beta^2$ to both be equal to $\varepsilon$.  But the only way for that to happen is if the exponent, 2, is equal to a multiple of the length of the cycle.  But since the lengths of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are odd, their lengths have to be at least 3, since if they were length 1, they would be the same as length 0.  So $\alpha^2$ and $\beta^2$ cannot be equal to $\varepsilon$, so $\alpha$ must be equal to $\beta$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: If $\alpha$ is an $n$-cycle and $k$ is relatively prime to $n$, then $\alpha^k$ determines $\alpha$. Prove this in general, then set $k=2$.

If you didn't have an assumption of odd length, two different transpositions would be a counterexample -- then $\alpha^2$ and $\beta^2$ are both the identity permutation.

Comment: Is the following proof sound?

The only way for $\alpha^2$ to be equal to $\beta^2$ while $\alpha \neq \beta$ is for $\alpha^2$ and $\beta^2$ to both be equal to $\varepsilon$.  But the only way for that to happen is if the exponent, 2, is equal to a multiple of the length of the cycle.  But since the lengths of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are odd, their lengths have to be at least 3, since if they were length 1, they would be the same as length 0.  So $\alpha^2$ and $\beta^2$ cannot be equal to $\varepsilon$, so $\alpha$ must be equal to $\beta$.

Comment: @Matt: The first sentence lacks a justification -- and is actually not true for even $n$; consider (1 2 3 4) and (1 4 3 2). Was my hint not clear? It would lead to a proof of the form: "Given any odd $n$ there is an $m$ such that $(\alpha^2)^m=\alpha$ for every $n$-cycle $\alpha$, namely blah blah blah. Therefore, if $\alpha^2=\beta^2$, then $\alpha=(\alpha^2)^m=(\beta^2)^m=\beta$."

Comment: But $(1 2 3 4)^2 = \varepsilon$ and $(1 4 3 2)^2 = \varepsilon$?  No, I'm sorry, I didn't understand your hint.  I'm not sure why.  I need to think about what you just wrote in order to understand it.  This stuff is not clear to me at all.

Comment: @Matt, um no. $(1\;2\;3\;4)^2=(1\;3)(2\;4)=(1\;4\;3\;2)^2$. Therefore they are a counterexample to your claim that $\alpha^2=\beta^2$ only when $\alpha^2=\varepsilon$. (I'm assuming that $\varepsilon$ is your notation for the identity permutation).

Comment: Oh sorry!  You're right, I was reading that wrong.  Yeah, I meant $\varepsilon$ as the identity permutation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that they are not disjoint. Pick one of the common elements, call it $x$. Now see what happens to it under both $\alpha^2$ and  $\beta^2$

Comment: It is still true if they _are_ disjoint, though. The parenthesis in the exercise probably ought to have said "not _necessarily_ disjoint".